# PHP mail() returns false but no error is logged

Tags: php, email

I've written a quick and dirty script for our content people to send out a newsletter to a distribution list. The script has been working fine for months so rewriting it with the PEAR mailer has been low on my priority list. Today the script failed to send out the email. The mail() function is returning false, and the email is not going out, but error_get_last() is null. What can I do to figure out why the script has suddenly stopped working?
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
ob_start();
readfile("/html-email/tt-facstaff");
$facstaff_content = utf8_decode(ob_get_contents());
ob_start();
readfile("/html-email/tt-students");
$students_content = utf8_decode(ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();

if($students_content === false || $facstaff_content === false) die("<h4>Failed to decode content.</h4>");
$all_content = $facstaff_content."\n\n".$students_content;

if(isset($_GET["go"]) && $_GET["go"] == "true"){
    $ppl = "redacted";
    $students = "redacted";
    $facstaff = "redacted";

    $subject = "Tech Times for ".date("m/d");
    $headers = "From: \"Tennessee Tech University\" <redacted>\r\n".
        "Reply-to: redacted\r\n".
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n".
        "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    $ok1 = mail($students,$subject,$students_content,$headers."\r\nBcc:".$ppl);
    $ok2 = mail($facstaff,$subject,$facstaff_content,$headers);

    if($ok1 && $ok2){
        echo("<html><body><div><h1 style=\"width:800px; margin:40px auto; text-align:center;\">Tech Times has been sent.</h1></div></body></html>");
    }else{
        $error = error_get_last();
        var_dump($error);
        echo("<html><body><div><h2 style=\"width:800px; margin:40px auto; text-align:center; color:#FF0000;\">Failed to send one or both editions of Tech Times!</h2></div></body></html>");
    }
}

echo $all_content;
echo("<html><body><div style=\"width:800px; margin:40px auto; text-align:center;\"><a href=\"/html-email/tech-times?go=true\">Send Tech Times</a></div></body></html>");
?>
```

Comment: There are no php error, don't look for php error dump. Do you have mail log access on the server?

Comment: Looks like the server can't let you do that, Dave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Check if sendmail is running on the server.
2. Check /var/log/maillog

Comment: maillog contains the following error:
Nov 15 09:52:11 localhost sendmail[2184]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(apache): can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/): Permission denied

Comment: You know what, I rebooted this VM and I bet SELinux has turned itself back on.

Comment: @Dave all else being equal, that's probably it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this right before your mail() function:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

Also, try running:

> service sendmail status
>
> service postfix status

This will inform us which of the major mail handlers you are using.

Comment: No dice. I think error_reporting is already set elsewhere to E_ALL anyway. This is a dev server.